# using Gatsby, the build fails,

Tags: build, gatsby

I get a new bug, when trying to do yarn build

```
  2 | //# sourceMappingURL=react-table.production.min.js.map
  3 |


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

image is attached
[image]

this is coming from a component that uses react-table, this is a new bug that "suddenly" happened.

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

As you can follow in [this Gatsby discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/26015) what ends in this [thread from `react-table`](https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/2071) the issue rises because of the `useAsyncDebounce` you're using, which internally uses `async`/`await`.

You have two solutions:

- Importing `regenerator-runtime/runtime` at the top of your component:

  ```
  import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
  import React from 'react';
  import {
     useAsyncDebounce,
     useFilters,
     useGlobalFilter,
     useTable,
  } from "react-table"
  ```
- Configuring your `browserlist` to include the polyfill automatically. In your `package.json`:

  ```
  {
     "browserslist": [">0.25%", "not dead", "since 2017-06"]
  }
  ```

  You have to add a version that’s recent enough to support `async`/`await`, so Babel does not try to add a polyfill. Check them at https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist